# Which pre-Socratic believed the sun was a burning bar of iron?

Tags: presocratics

I had it in my head that it was Anaximander, but I'm not finding it (and it's been a couple of decades since this concept was introduced to me;)  Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Burning mass of iron, and [it was Anaxagoras](https://www.utm.edu/staff/jfieser/class/110/1-presocratics.htm). He was sentenced to death for claiming it, allegedly, with execution replaced by exile. But I am not sure this is a question about philosophy.

Comment: @Conifold Isn't it about pre-Socratic philosophy?  (ID question for a concept. My interest is in applied philosophy, as related to General Artificial Intelligence, which is why I'm starting out with the pre-Socratics instead of Kant.  This one was just for fun, as stars are the source of heavy elements, such as metals.) If you want to answer formally, I'll up-vote and accept.  I appreciate your taking the time to correct my faulty recollection.